# VBA query loop scripting.dictionary

Tags: vba, excel, dictionary, while-loop

I've got this:

```
 Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    rn = 2
    Do While ThisWorkbook.Sheets("1").Range("B" & rn).Value <> ""
        If (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("1").Range("B" & rn).Value <> "") Then dict("&&1") = dict & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("1").Range("B" & rn).Value & ", "
        rn = rn + 1
    Loop
```

But this doesn't work, I get error 450 in VBA.

What it needs to do is the following: Each value in column B (if it's not empty) has to be added into the dict seperated by a comma. Ofcourse after the last line it may not set a comma.

I think I am on the right way but there are missing things.

Comment: A `Dictionary`  is usualy used to store unique keys, and then per each unique key to add values related to that unique key. Why do you need a `Dictionary` for your task ? what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: With the dict I want to search from all costumers their addresses. So I do exactly with it what you explained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all the unique values to a string you could modify your code as follows

Note that you should use `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)` not `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("1")`

*pls use `MsgBox Left$(strOut, Len(strOut) - 2)` to fix the trailing non-required portion*

```
Sub a()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim strOut As String

Set ws = Sheets(1)

    rn = 2
    Do While ws.Range("B" & rn).Value <> ""
        If Len(ws.Range("B" & rn).Value) > 0 Then
            If dict.exists(ws.Range("B" & rn).Value) Then
              Else
                dict.Add ws.Range("B" & rn).Value, 1
            strOut = strOut & (ws.Range("B" & rn).Value & ", ")
            End If
        End If
        rn = rn + 1
    Loop
    MsgBox strOut
End Sub
```

Comment: That's awesome, it's working! I have a few questions to understand it better. You used strOut to combine all the value's, why isn't dict("&&1") a good solution here? And sadly after the last value it places a comma, how to prevent this?

Comment: I used the dictionary to simply store the unique values. While you could have then iterated through the dictionary items to get the values, I did it directly with a loop. Will fix the trailing characters!

Comment: In my own way I fix it like this      strOut = Left(strOut, Len(strOut) - 2). Sadly, when I use my method to call it, it's not working. Call MOD_SQL.ExecQuery(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\SQL Files\Info.sql", 
                                                    "QueryResult", 
                                                    dict, 
                                                     "B1", 
                                                    "QueryResult")                                       Do I need to put dict there or strOut or something else?

Comment: When I do dict("&&1") = strOut, it works, sorry for the inconvience! And thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

just to throw in a more condensed version of brettdj solution

```
Sub main()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim strOut As String

    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        For Each cell In Sheets(1).Range("B2", Sheets(1).Cells(.Rows.Count, "B")).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues)
            .Item(cell.Value) = 1
        Next
        strOut = Join(.keys, ",")
        MsgBox strOut
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Sadly, when I use my method to call it, it's not working. Call MOD_SQL.ExecQuery(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\SQL Files\Info.sql", "QueryResult", dict, "B1", "QueryResult") Do I need to put dict there or strOut or something else?

Comment: It's not working" says nothing useful. But this is a completely different issue from your _original_ OP and much broader: you may want to make a new post with all necessary details to catch the issue

Comment: I already fixed it, stupid mistake (see comment above your solution)